# Running threads in parallel takes more time then sequential execution in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, onnxruntime

I have two ONNX deep learned models.
I want to run both the models parallelly.
I am using threads from python. But surprisingly it is taking more time then running both the models sequentially.

Task to be done.

1. make a class of model
2. load both the models in the *init* of that class.
3. run both the models parallelly for inferencing on the given input.

Is this normal behavior.
please suggest the workaround to this?

```
class ModelImp:

def __init__(self):
    print('loading model...')
    # Load your model here
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    model_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "model", "hatev5.onnx")
    self.hate_sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_path)
    self.hate_input_name = self.hate_sess.get_inputs()[0].name
    self.hate_seq_len=15
    self.corona_seq_len=16
    print('********************************Hate model loaded.**********************************************************')
    model_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "model", "corona.onnx")
    self.corona_sess = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_path)
    self.corona_input_name = self.corona_sess.get_inputs()[0].name
    # self.model = keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={"gelu": gelu})
    # print(self.model.summary())
    print('********************************Corona model loaded.**********************************************************')
    print("_________________________************MODEL.py : loading tokenizer ************___________________________")
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    vocab_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "model", "vocab.txt")
    self.wordpiece_tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_path, do_lower_case=True)
    tokenizer_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "model", "hate_tokenizer.json")
    with open(tokenizer_path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        self.hate_tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(data)
    print("_________________________************ HATE MODEL.py : tokenizer loaded************___________________________")
    tokenizer_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "model", "corona_tokenizer.json")
    with open(tokenizer_path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        self.corona_tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(data)
    print("_________________________************ CORONA MODEL.py : tokenizer loaded************___________________________")
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
# string version of Eval
# data is a string
def thread_eval(self,data,q):
    # print("--------------------------------------corona started----------------------------------------------------------")
    corona_lines = []
    corona_line = ' '.join(trim(self.wordpiece_tokenizer.tokenize(data.strip()), self.corona_seq_len))
    corona_lines.append(corona_line)
    # print(texts)
    corona_line_1 = self.corona_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(corona_lines)
    corona_line_2 = sequence.pad_sequences(corona_line_1, padding='post', maxlen=self.corona_seq_len)
    corona_pred = self.corona_sess.run(None, {self.corona_input_name: corona_line_2})
    corona_prob = corona_pred[0][0][1]
    q.put(corona_prob)
    # print("---------------------------------------corona ended------------------------------------------------------------")
def Eval(self, data):

    try:
        
        
        # pre_start = time.time()
        # mp = ModelImp()
        # with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph: #tf.device(config['gpu_device'] )

        # print(data)
        d = json.loads(data)
        out_json = {}

        if (not (("query" in d) or ("Query" in d))):
            # print("Query: ",data)
            score = -2 * 10000  # new_change
            output = {"Output": [[score]]}  # {"score" :score,"Succ" : False }
            output_str = json.dumps(output)
            return output_str
        if ("query" in d):
            query = d["query"][0]  # new_change
            # print("Query 1: ",query)
        elif ("Query" in d):
            query = d["Query"][0]  # new_change
            # print("Query 2: ",query)
        if (len(query.strip()) == 0):
            query = "good"
            # print("Query 3: ",query)
        ## HATE MODEL input preprocess
        que = queue.Queue()
        x = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_eval, args=(query,que),daemon=True)
        x.start()
        hate_lines = []
        hate_line = ' '.join(trim(self.wordpiece_tokenizer.tokenize(query.strip()), self.hate_seq_len))
        hate_lines.append(hate_line)
        # print(texts)
        hate_line_1 = self.hate_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(hate_lines)
        hate_line_2 = sequence.pad_sequences(hate_line_1, padding='post', maxlen=self.hate_seq_len)
        ## CORONA MODEL input preprocess
        
        # print(line_2)
        
        # print("----------------------------------------hate started----------------------------------------")
        hate_pred = self.hate_sess.run(None, {self.hate_input_name: hate_line_2})
        # print("----------------------------------------hate ended----------------------------------------")
        # print("pred: ",pred[0])
        # prob = math.exp(pred[0][0][1])/(math.exp(pred[0][0][0]) + math.exp(pred[0][0][1]))
        hate_prob = hate_pred[0][0][1]
        # print("hate_prob: ",hate_prob)
        # hate_score = int(hate_prob * 10000)  # new_change  
        x.join()          
        corona_prob=que.get()
        # print("pred: ",pred[0])
        # prob = math.exp(pred[0][0][1])/(math.exp(pred[0][0][0]) + math.exp(pred[0][0][1]))
        
        # print("corona_prob: ",corona_prob)
        output_prob = max(corona_prob,hate_prob)
        # corona_score = int(corona_prob * 10000)  # new_change
        output_score = int(output_prob * 10000)

        output = {"Output": [[output_score]]}  # {"score" :score,"Succ" : True }
        output_str = json.dumps(output)

        return output_str

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: ",data)
        score = -3 * 10000  # new_change
        output = {"Output": [[score]]}  # {"score" :score,"Succ" : False }
        output_str = json.dumps(output)
        print(e)
        return output_str
```

Comment: Can't see any code. Despite that, Python multithreading is generally not useful for speeding up CPU-bound workloads.

Comment: @couka Is there any way to use multiple cores of the CPU in python?

Comment: @couka Yes, there are multiple options for using multiple cores with python. Since your code doesn't look amenable to NumPy, you might wish to start with the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in the standard library.

Comment: A more difficult option would be to write a C extension that uses OpenMP, and link that to your Python code. [Cython](https://cython.org/) supports [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/), and is one of the relatively easy ways to write C extensions.

Comment: If I may expand on the other comments, Python has a "global interpreter lock" that ensures that only one thread at a time is executing Python code.  It works great if most of your threads are waiting on I/O or a socket, but the only way to get true simultaneous multithreading is to use a C module like numpy.